# Symfony2 validation constraint 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\MaxLength' not found

Tags: class, validation, symfony

I am new to Symfony and frameworks so have been following the Symblog tutorial but have become stuck when validating the forms.

Get this error...

> FatalErrorException: Error: Class
>   'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\MaxLength' not found in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Portfolio/Symfony/src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Enquiry.php
>   line 71

Where am I going wrong?

B

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MaxLength` is deprecated since symfony 2.1 use `Length` with the `max` option set.

The reference can be found in [UPGRADE-2.1.md](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md#validator) in the validator section.

Comment: Thanks for that...from one problem to another though! Gotta love it else i would throw my computer out the window!